# how can i integrate multiple popup window

Tags: jquery, popup

i had a table with three feilds name edit and delete.

```
enter code here
   <table width="200" border="1">
   <tr>
        <td><B>Name</b></td>
        <td><b>Edit</b></td>
        <td><b>Delete</b></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>ABC</td>
         <td><a href="#">update</a></td>
         <td>delete</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>BCCD</td>
         <td><a href="#">update</a></td>
         <td>delete</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

i want to open a popup dialog box form to update this feild using jquery.. for ex- abc update. i click on update link next to abc a popup should open with a textfeild and that abc value in it..
like wise i want to do for rest in the list... In this example i had just put two row but in real my table will be generated from database and it will have n feild..

**Thanks**

Comment: Hi, this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow, as it's a mere coding request.

Comment: See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <a href="#" class='update'>update</a>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     $('.update').click(function(){
      $(this).dialog();

     });


     </script>
```

refer to that link : http://jqueryui.com/dialog/